# Where to add headers to a POST request in angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

I'm trying to upload a picture and send a post request to spring rest controller so it can save it .

I'm working with jwt so i need to past the JWT header inside the POST request .

this is the UploadFile.service.ts

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {

    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.host+'/post', {
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'text'
});

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

I want to know where i can add the header :

```
{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})}
```

in the post request , i have tried to add it behind , {reportProgres .. } , but it doesnt seem correct as im getting errors about th header .

Any idea ?

This is what i'm trying but it's like 'init' instead of option :

[image]

**I'm using HTTPCLIENT**

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }
  let neededHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); 
  neededHeaders.append('Authorization', this.authService.getToken());
  const req = this.http.post(this.host+'/post', body, {headers: neededHeaders, reportProgress: true, responseType: 'text'});
```

[From the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
  headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
   reportProgress?: boolean;
   responseType: 'text';
});
```

Comment: but what about {
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'text'
} ?

Comment: I did the same as you but it's not correct yet , can you please see my post again

Comment: did you import RequestOptions? pass headers to RequestOptions() and then pass that options to your post req

Comment: No becaus i did add headers directly after { reportProgress: true, responseType: 'text' } as in your exemple

Comment: no HTTP Post will expect options and we are passing Headers directly which should not be the case. It is like `this.http.post(url, body, options);`. So create the options pass headers to it and use that RequestOptions as i mentioned in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173708/discussion-between-avinash-and-des12zer).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the header frequently you can use [interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
        const req = r.clone({
            headers: r.headers.set('Authorization', this.authService.getToken()),
            body: req.body
        });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}

export const tokenInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

Add it to the `providers` of the module.

```
@NgModule({
     providers: [tokenInterceptorProvider]
})
```

Comment: Okey , Let me try this